# Run a keyword at the background in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to RobotFramework, I am looking to execute Run PlanA to run background so that RunPlanB keyword can start executing, Maybe a parallel execution. How it's possible

```
Run PlanA
Run PlanB
```

Run PlanA to execute in background

Answer (score 0):

If there are no tests involved, those tasks are better to be done at Operating System level, i.e. a batch or shell script file.

With Robot Framework you should look at Process library.

Comment: Tests are involved. robotframework-async is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with robot. Robot itself has no ability to run tests simultaneously within a single invocation. Your only option is to run robot twice.